# Powerapps Visible function

Tags: ms-office, powerapps

For some reason the Visible function in my Powerapps won't work I just wrote in `OnSelect() Mail.Visible = false` 
The Mail is in this case a Textinput/ TextBox.
When I click on the button nothing happens. I can't find a documentation about it on the MS Website but I have in Powerapps a fuction called "Visible"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit @SeaDude

This worked perfectly for me toggling the variable back and forth to show/hide a few layers.

```
Set(mailVisible, !mailVisible)
```

Comment: Need to mention where `mailVisible` gets used, the syntax, etc. This answer is incomplete.

Answer (score 5):

You need to create a variable in the button's (or another control) `OnSelect` property:

```
UpdateContext({ mailVisible: false })
```

And set the `Visible` property of the `Mail` control to `mailVisible`. You may need to initialize that variable to `true`, for example, in the screen's `OnVisible` property:

```
UpdateContext({ mailVisible: true })
```

PowerApps works similarly to Excel - you cannot, by an action, change directly the value of a cell (e.g., `A1 = 42`). But you can make the A1 cell reference another cell (say, `=A4`), so when you change the value of the cell `A4`, A1 will be updated as well. The same principle applies in PowerApps - you cannot change the value of a property from an action, but you can update the value that the property references.

Comment: Some additional functions to consider are: 
`Set(mailVisible, !mailVisible)` and `UpdateContext({mailVisible: !mailVisible})`. I prefer using `Set()` instead of `UpdateContext()`. Whichever you choose, be sure to stick with the convention throughout your app. Mixing `Set` and `UpdateContext` with the same variable will cause issues.

Comment: Should probably set the variable in the `OnStart` of App instead of `OnVisible` of the screen, because most developers would look at App and not the screen's property when looking for where variables are set. And @SeaDude's comment was spot on and worth a mention, too - that `Set()` and `UpdateContext()` can't be co-mingled.

Answer (score 2):

So I have a few items like this. I'm not sure if this is the BEST way, but I know it works.

Set a variable on the App's `OnStart`:

```
OnStart = Set(variable_visible, "");
```

Button code:

```
OnSelect = Set(variable_visible,"1");
```

Item that you want visible:

```
Visible = If(variable_visible="1", true, false);
```

Edit: You can reset your variable at any point to hide that section.
Sometimes Power Apps fights you on things that seem correct.

Answer (score 0):

The Visible will the condition that is true to make it show.

For example

If I have one TextBox named TextInput1 and I want a control to be visible when the Text entered = true it will be. For this example use a label.

Label1's visible function will be TextInput1.Text = "true"

This will show when the input text will be true. if it's false or anything else the label won't show. This is a very basic use of the visible but can be used in many ways.

Answer (score 0):

In On select property of button you can't set any other control property directly.
you need to follow the steps as:

1- you need to set a boolean type variable on OnSelect of button e.g.
Set(varShowMail,false)

2- go to TextInput Mail and select its Visible property and assign the variable "varShowMail"

It will work 100%.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set on visible of screen property UpdateContext({ Var_Visible: false})
2. set a variable on control "select" or "change" to true"UpdateContext({ Var_Visible: true})" and use the variable in other control visible property that you want to show or hide, if required you can use condition to set a variable to true or false